# Div on bottom of page

Tags: css, html, footer

on my website i want the footer at the bottom of the site. i add this to the footer css:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

The footer is now good at the bottom but all the content goes on the footer div. Like the footer div is background. How can i put the footer at the bottom right?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking two different questions. Try raising the z-index of the footer element to keep it above other content.

To put it at the bottom right, set a width and a right position of zero.

Comment: i have now the footer on the bottom. but on one page i have a lot of content and the footer appears at the middle of the page over the content.

Comment: That'll be virtually impossible to diagnose without some code or a demo. (Put it in your question, not here.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem but you can try to add/change this in your footer css

```
right: 0;
width: 50%;
z-index: 999;
```

Comment: i added it but now the footer is only right but same problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make use of the CSS [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/CR-CSS21-20070719/visuren.html#z-index) property and give your main content container `padding-bottom` equal to the height of the footer to prevent your footer *cutting off* the bottom of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article "How to keep footers at the bottom of the page":

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

You will want to compensate for the height of the footer by adding the footer's height to the margin-bottom of your content's region. First, look for the element that appears right before your footer on every page. Hopefully it will be something like this:

```
<div id="header">
    HEADER CONTENT
</div>
<div id="content" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
    YOUR SITES CONTENT
</div>
<div id="footer" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px;>
    FOOTER CONTENT
</div>
```

Also, don't use inline styles like I have above. Use propper css please :) It helps all the internets.

Answer (score 0):

Position: fixed takes the element out of the flow of the page. The result is that your footer is occupying "nothing" when it comes to affecting your other elements.
The reason your content is ending up on top is that it doesn't actually know it's there. What I mean is that you need to account for your footer when thinking of your other elements.
For instance, if you have a wrapper that ends just before your footer, you can give it an extra bottom padding that is equivalent to the height of your footer.

To answer a sort of hidden second part of your question: To be able to give an element a z-index, it needs to be position with something other than "static" (the default positioning). If you're trying to work out z-indexes on two different elements, you'll want to give them both a position value other than "static" to get total control.

Hope some of this helps,
iso